# Cyrillic words when using polyglossia and lualatex

Tags: polyglossia, font-encodings, cyrillic

Consider the following example where I've added the font settings that I use (I know it's not completely minimal but I have all the code in case it is important):

```
% lualatex test.tex

\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Ligatures      = {
    TeX,
    CommonOff
  }
]{texgyrepagella}
%\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{texgyrepagella} % <-- That didn't work!
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\setmathfont[
  version  = bold,
  FakeBold = 4
]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}
\setotherlanguages{russian}

\begin{document}

\textrussian{Па́вел Алексе́евич Черенко́в}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen, the output is wrong.

How do I get the correct Cyrillic output?

**Note**

The "real" document is typeset in Danish but I need the single Russian name typeset in Cyrillic.

Comment: you need a font with cyrillic glyphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use a font that supports Cyrillic and no TeX Gyre font does. On my system, Palatino does. You might need to look for a Cyrillic Palatino (or change fonts altogether).

```
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{texgyrepagella}[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Ligatures      = {
    TeX,
    CommonOff
  }
]
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Palatino} % <-- That didn't work!
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[
  version  = bold,
  FakeBold = 4
]

\setdefaultlanguage{danish}
\setotherlanguages{russian}

\begin{document}

\textrussian{Па́вел Алексе́евич Черенко́в}

\end{document}
```

Don't mix package loading and setting.

[image]

Comment: I ended up using `NewCM10-Regular`. ... and now for something (not) completely different: Why don't mix package loading and settings? I've never experienced any problems when doing this.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I did (personally and answering questions here). The main reason is that the preamble is much easier to maintain.